# how to set capabilities (setcap) on perf

Tags: ubuntu, perf, setcap

I'd like to use the perf utility. I was following instructions to set up a privileged group of users who are permitted to execute performance monitoring and observability without limits (as instructed here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/perf-security.html). I added the group and limited access to users not in the group. I started having problems when assigning capabilities to the perf tool:

```
setcap cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_syslog=ep perf
```

I get an invalid arguments error saying

```
fatal error: Invalid argument
usage: setcap [-q] [-v] [-n <rootid>] (-r|-|<caps>) <filename> [ ... (-r|-|<capsN>) <filenameN> ]

Note <filename> must be a regular (non-symlink) file.
```

But running `stats perf` gives me this

```
  File: ./perf
  Size: 1622        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 10307h/66311d   Inode: 35260925    Links: 1
Access: (0750/-rwxr-x---)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: ( 1001/perf_users)
Access: 2021-12-03 13:08:48.923220351 +0100
Modify: 2021-11-05 17:02:56.000000000 +0100
Change: 2021-12-03 12:31:49.451991980 +0100
 Birth: -
```

which says the file is a regular file. What could be the problem? How can I set the capabilities for the Perf tool?

Linux distribution: Ubuntu 20.04

EDIT:
Last 20 output lines of `strace setcap cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_syslog=ep perf`:

```
munmap(0x7f825054c000, 90581)           = 0
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, CAP_MAC_OVERRIDE) = 1
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, 0x30 /* CAP_??? */) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, 0x28 /* CAP_??? */) = 1
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, 0x2c /* CAP_??? */) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, 0x2a /* CAP_??? */) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
prctl(PR_CAPBSET_READ, 0x29 /* CAP_??? */) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55de3e858000
brk(0x55de3e879000)                     = 0x55de3e879000
capget({version=_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, pid=0}, NULL) = 0
capget({version=_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, pid=0}, {effective=0, permitted=0, inheritable=0}) = 0
capget({version=_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, pid=0}, NULL) = 0
capset({version=_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, pid=0}, {effective=1<<CAP_SETFCAP, permitted=0, inheritable=0}) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0x1), ...}) = 0
write(3, "unable to set CAP_SETFCAP effect"..., 72unable to set CAP_SETFCAP effective capability: Operation not permitted
) = 72
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Add the last 20 output lines of `strace setcap cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_syslog=ep perf` to your queston.

Comment: @HaukeLaging I updated the question with the requested information.

Comment: According to the strace output you should get `unable to set CAP_SETFCAP effective capability: Operation not permitted` message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was experiencing this too, and was able to get it working by building and installing the latest version of `libcap` from source. This may not be the best solution, but it worked for me.

[libcap-2.53](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/morgan/libcap/+/refs/tags/libcap-2.53)

```
$ git clone https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/morgan/libcap
$ cd libcap
$ git checkout libcap-2.53
$ make
$ make test
$ make sudotest
$ sudo make install
```

I ran the tests to confirm everything was working before install.

Once it had been installed I was able to run the commands listed in the [perf-security](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/perf-security.html) doc as expected.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Thank you so much!

Comment: Could installing this version of libcap over the system one cause issues? I'm struggling to find info about that online.

Answer (score 0):

This question is 2 years old but I think it might be useful to answer anyway.

A had a similar problem and I noticed that `/usr/bin/perf` was a shell script.

```
$ file /usr/bin/perf
/usr/bin/perf: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
```

It called `/usr/lib/linux-tools/6.5.0-26-generic/perf` (my kernel version is 6.5.0-26-generic), which was a symbolic link for `/usr/lib/linux-hwe-6.5-tools-6.5.0-26/perf`. When I called `setcap` in the real executable file it finally worked.

```
$ sudo setcap cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_syslog=ep /usr/lib/linux-hwe-6.5-tools-6.5.0-26/perf
```